# How does Elasticsearch search documents? How to customize preprocess pipeline and scoring functions in ES?

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I want to implement Elasticsearch on a customized corpus. I have installed elasticsearch of version `7.5.1` and I do all my work in `python` using the official client.

Here I have a few questions:

1. How to customize preprocess pipeline? For example, I want to use a BertTokenizer to convert strings to tokens instead of ngrams
2. How to customize scoring function of each document w.r.t. the query? For example, I want to compare effects of `tf-idf` with `bm25`, or even using some neural models for scoring.

If there is great tutorial **in python**, please share with me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your use-case exactly? In which way is your corpus customized?

Comment: @samy Actually I'm doing a research project in recommendation. I designed a model that is able to generate some query for the user, and I would like to check how this query can be implemented in candidate recall.

Comment: fyi 7.5 is [EOL](https://www.elastic.co/support/eol), you should really use 7.15 as it's latest

Comment: You could also have a look at the More Like This query, it can be useful for building a quick recommendation system: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-mlt-query.html

Comment: Thank you samy, I think it's what I want indeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can customize the similarity function when creating an index. See the [Similarity Module section](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules-similarity.html) of the documentation. You can find a good article that compares classical TF_IDF with BM25 on the [OpenSource Connections site](https://opensourceconnections.com/blog/2015/10/16/bm25-the-next-generation-of-lucene-relevation/).

In general, Elasticsearch uses an [inverted index](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/documents-indices.html) to look up all documents that contain a specific word or token.

It sounds like you want to use vector fields for scoring, there is a [good article on the elastic blog](https://www.elastic.co/blog/text-similarity-search-with-vectors-in-elasticsearch) that explains how you can achieve that. Be aware that [as of now](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/78473) Elasticsearch is not using vector fields for retrieval, only for scoring, if you want to use vector fields for retrieval you have to use a plugin, or the [OpenSearch](https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/search-plugins/knn/index/) fork, or wait for version 8.

In my opinion, using ANN in real-time during search is too slow and expensive, and i have yet to see improvements in relevancy with normal search requests.

I would do the preprocessing of your documents in your own python environment before indexing and not use any Elasticsearch pipelines or plugins. It is easier to debug and iterate outside of Elasticsearch.

You could also take a look at the [Haystack Project](https://github.com/deepset-ai/haystack), it might have a lot of the functionality that you are looking for, already build in.

Comment: Thank you samy. I'm going to deep dive into it. One remaining question: how does Elasticsearch search a document by default?

Comment: try https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.15/search-your-data.html as an intro

Comment: The core data structure in Elasticsearch is an inverted index you can read more about that here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/documents-indices.html and here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_index
Basically elasticsaerch takes the tokens or words from documents and stores a mapping token -> list of docs in this index. When you search, it takes the tokens or words from your search and looks up and merges & scores all documents that are associated with these tokens/words. 
I added a link that explains that in more detail to the answer.

Comment: I got it. Thanks a lot samy.